# How to show specific gutenberg blocks based on page-template chosen

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks, acfpro

I am trying to make some gutenberg blocks visible on specific page-templates only, so that it is hidden if not a certain template is chosen. 
I know it possible with custom post types, but can't find a solution for page-templates.

I have also tried using ACF PRO and making a 'Show this field group if' on the specific block && page template, but it doesn't work either.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code, please.

Answer (score 1):

ACF Pro does it. The block won't show any inputs if chosen in an area where it's not allowed. Just put a message in the render block for the admin.[image][image]